# How to append numbers into input field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a calculator using javascript (Trying to advance my skills) and I ran into an issue with trying to add more than one number to the input field(The area where the numbers should show).

```
$('.Buttons').click(function() { 
    var getValue = this.value;
    if($('#Result').is(':empty')) {
        document.getElementById('Result').value = getValue
    }
    else {
       /* document.getElementById('Result').appendChild(document.createTextNode(getValue)); */
       resultBox = $("#Result").value + getValue
    }
});
```

Should I use a `<div>` as the input and simply used the .innerHTML method to change it instead? Sorry if I sound noobish, I just took a javascript test was rated mediocre -_- :( So I'm going to practice Javascript more often now.

Comment: What is `resultBox`?

Comment: document.getElementById('Result').value = document.getElementById('Result').value + getValue;

Comment: Are you just appending digits here? e.g. the buttons each have a number?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  Yes, each button has a value of the number assigned. I want to perform operations with them once entered

Comment: That makes more sense now. Please provide sample HTML next time too :) If you want to use decimal values, convert using `Number()` and not `parseFloat()`. It will convert blank strings to `0` (which is better for your  calculator)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work fine if you need to append the new pressed number to the "display" field

```
$('.Buttons').click(function() { 
    document.getElementById('Result').value += ''+this.value;
});
```

Comment: Why mix raw selectors with jQuery? Be a lot shorter in jQuery only.

Comment: This worked! However, TrueBlueAussie was saying that the value was being viewed as a string rather than a number. would I use the number function to change that?

Comment: @JamellDaniels no if you only need to append more numbers to the input field.  you have to convert to numbers your values if you need to make some operations with them

Comment: @JamellDaniels Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert strings to numbers.